# tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

And this is the traceback django provides me.

```
if getattr(response, 'xframe_options_exempt', False):
    return response

response['X-Frame-Options'] = self.get_xframe_options_value(request,response)
return response

def get_xframe_options_value(self, request, response):
```

Get the value to set for the X_FRAME_OPTIONS header. Use the value from
the X_FRAME_OPTIONS setting, or 'DENY' if not set.

This method can be overridden if needed, allowing it to vary based on
the request or response.

```
return getattr(settings, 'X_FRAME_OPTIONS', 'DENY').upper()
```

I have a hard time figuring out why this error occurs. How can i find out where that tuple is in my code?
THIS IS ONE VIEW OF ONE APPLICATION

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import destination
# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    dests=destination.objects.all()

    return render(request,'index.html',{'dests':dests}),
```

NOW THIS IS SECOND VIEW

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
def HOMEE(request):
    return render(request,'HOMEE.html'),
```

Comment: Remove the trailing comma in `return render(..)`

Answer (score 0):

As Willem said in the comments you have to remove the trailing comma in :

```
return render(request,'index.html',{'dests':dests}),
```

The reason behind this is in python you can create tuple just by writing different objects separated by a comma. So

```
return render(request,'index.html',{'dests':dests}),
```

actually equals `return (render(request,'index.html',{'dests':dests}), )`

You can try it quite easily in the console :

[image]